# jquery lightbox view slidershow

Tags: jquery

I have a list of images. I want to show full size images using lightbox. But i dont want lightbox to work on click of those images. I want lightbox to work with click of some other link saying "Start Slide Show".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid your requirement may require tinkering with the jquery.lightbox-0.5.js. Can't you make do with a plugin like [jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) which is meant for slideshows which is more in line with your requirement.